# MATLAB Weighted Multiple Regression

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, weighted

I have a set of data that includes 821 observations, each with 20 measurements. I would like to regress this set data against a set of single dependent variables using a multiple linear regression in MATLAB. However, I would also like to weight each observation differently in the regression based on my own calculations. For example, I would like to give the first observation a weight of 1 and the second observation a weight of 1.6, which would ideally pull the regression towards the more heavily weighted second observation.

Is such a computation possible in MATLAB? If so, what function(s) would be best to carry out this type of computation?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Statistics Toolbox, you can use [`fitlm`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html) to create a linear regression model, applying the `Weights` option to supply your weights.

NB in older versions of MATLAB, you'll need to use `LinearModel.fit` rather than `fitlm`, but they do the same thing.

Comment: Great, thanks! So would the proper implementation of the code look something like `mdl = LinearModel.fit(X,y,'linear','Weights',w)`, where `w` is an 821x1 vector of the corresponding observation weights?

Answer (score 2):

You do not actually need the *Statistics Toolbox* to do this. The built-in function `lscov` will do everything you want.

> `[b,bse] = lscov(X,y,w)`

will provide weighted OLS estimates and their standard errors. If you would like a constant in the regression then include a column of ones in X.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would the results of this function differ at all from those of the `LinearModel.fit` approach? Also, is there a way to see the adjusted R squared value using this function?

Comment: The results from both methods will be the same. Using the LinearModel class is probably more convenient (outputs summary statistics and fit statistics, accepts more data types as inputs), but not everyone has access to the _Statistics Toolbox_. If you want the R-square or adjusted-R-square using `lscov` then you will have to calculate it by comparing the model predictions to the actual data (completely straightforward -- the Wikipedia article has the formula if you need it).